# swiper doesn't work on page load

Tags: swiper.js, pageload

I imported the code from https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/23-thumbs-gallery.html

But the first problem I had was that the slider didn't show so I fixed that with adding `min-height: 250px;` to the div class .swiper-slide(this is the only thing I changed), my new problem is that the slider doesn't work.
When I resize the browser the slider suddenly works, I can't find what is causing the problem. 

You can watch the slider at [nielsvt.remvoo.com](http://nielsvt.remvoo.com) and then section portfolio, the slider will be visible at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I simply fixed it by initializing the swiper once the page loads.

```
useEffect(()=> {
    swiper.init()
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

On the swiper section definition put the observer property true.

```
const swiper = new Swiper(swiperIdentifier, {
      ...
      observer: true,
    });
```